# Can the identity permutation be expressed as a product of disjoint transpositions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutation-cycles

I can only think of expressing it as the product of zero disjoint transpositions, but I don't know if the product of zero transpositions is even defined, or if it equals identity.

Comment: it is defined. The empty product is defined to be the identity

Comment: And the empty product is the only way to get the identity as a product of disjoint transpositions.

Comment: Thanks. I found a reference in Serge Lang's graduate Algebra book. I'm quite annoyed that my current book doesn't explain this before throwing at me an exercise that requires knowing it!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> It might have been polite for your book to note the fact; on the other hand, if we have a shelf of books in a particular order, swap two of them, and then perform finitely many additional swaps that do not move either of the original books, then the books are not in their original order.